# Server-side redirect if not logged in

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

I use Cloud Endpoints and do client-side oauth to access my backend. This works fine, except that it means I can only check whether the person hitting up my app URL is a user or not after the whole page and attached scripts have loaded and the oauth request has completed.

I'd like to enable server-side authentication so that I can use the same URL for my landing page and my app, and redirect the person to the app if she is a user or to the landing page if she isn't.

The problem is that the [User Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code) uses the [UserService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/) for authentication whereas Cloud Endpoints uses the [OAuth Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/#Java_OAuth_and_App_Engine). I can't figure out how to use OAuth in my [redirect filter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Filters) because all the links from the OAuth section linked to above are for OAuth 1 and [are deprecated](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#RequestToken).

How can I check in my redirect filter whether the person visiting is a user or not and simultaneously get a token that I can use to subsequently call my endpoints if she is a user?

I'm using the [Google Api JS client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) to make calls to cloud endpoints, so the solution would optimally integrate with that, using `gapi.auth.setToken(token)` with the token retrieved and bypass the whole `gapi.auth.authorize(params, callback)` dance.

Comment: are you looking to use the user API or OAuth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide custom servlet implementaion for login flow where You will fetch oauth-token by providing new Flow and then validate that access token to grant authorization of protected resources.

Google provides good reference document [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#authorization_code_flow) and You can use [this](https://github.com/manoj-pathak30/google-api-java-client-samples) sample code repo
for reference.

Comment: Decided to circumvent the problem for now. This looks very promising, so awarding the bounty. May comment again in the future if I have issues with implementation. Thanks for the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user API for endpoints, no need to use OAuth if doesn't suit your needs. You only need to add an parameter of the type `com.google.appengine.api.users.User` to your endpoint. As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth).

Eg:

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "scores.insert")
    public Score insert(Score score, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException {
      //Check if user is null
      //Do your thing

    }
```

Comment: That's how I have them set up. I was under the impression that the user API uses OAuth. I need a token on the client side in order to call my endpoints with the `Authorization` header set. But I get that token using client-side oauth flow. Instead, I'd like to get that token on the server side so that I can return a login screen if the user isn't logged in or a token if she is.

Comment: I have implement Oauth 2.0  for similar scenario where if user visit my web application through UI then Basic authentication will be used. User can access rest api through valid Oauth token.

Comment: @willlma I actually not even using the userAPI (which does NOT use OAith btw) .We built a very basic schema where we send the token on the client side and retieve it by using request.getHeader("Authorization")